Axios interceptor using socket option and rabbitmq+socket option
Issue:
While the interceptors work fine under normal load, they struggle with a high volume of requests and responses. When the load increases significantly, RabbitMQ and WebSocket servers sometimes can't handle the amount of data, leading to dropped requests and responses.
import axios from 'axios';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

// Request Interceptor
function requestInterceptor() {
axios.interceptors.request.use((request) =\> {
const requestId = 'REQ\_' + uuidv4();
request.meta = {
...request.meta,
requestId,
requestStartedAt: new Date().getTime(),
};

    // RabbitMQ and WebSocket logic 
    
    return request;

});
}

// Response Interceptor
function responseInterceptor() {
axios.interceptors.response.use(
(response) =\> {
const execTimeMs = new Date().getTime() - response.config.meta.requestStartedAt;
const execTimeSeconds = execTimeMs / 1000;

      console.log(`Execution time for ${response.config.url}: ${execTimeSeconds} seconds`);
    
      // RabbitMQ and WebSocket logic 
    
      return response;
    },
    (error) => {
      // Error handling (unchanged)
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

);
}

requestInterceptor();
responseInterceptor();

export default {
get: axios.get,
post: axios.post,
put: axios.put,
delete: axios.delete,
};
\`
export const defaultAxios = axios;

Question:
Do I need to change my code to handle high volumes of requests more efficiently, or is this an issue better addressed by  DevOps team through load balancing and scaling strategies?
i have made a queue for socket that pushes 10 every 10 seconds and it still lose some responses and requests
